# Viewing Family Group Sheet using Ancestry.com?

Tags: ancestry.com, family-tree

Before Ancestry.com upgraded its interface in early 2016, there was a button on a person's profile page to create a family group sheet that I often used to see at a glance whether all the children ascribed to a marriage were born in a sequence at places that "made sense".

That button seems to no longer be present there or anywhere else in the Ancestry GUI.

If I am not simply overlooking it, how can I easily see when and where all children of a marriage were born in a single screen now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In May 2019 it seems to be possible to access the family group sheet feature through a person's profile page once again.

It is the bottom choice on the pulldown from the tree name at upper left of a person's profile page.

[image]

and the Family Group Sheet has this appearance:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In April 2016, as far as I am aware, the Family Group Sheet view has not been reinstated on the New Ancestry. However, you can access a Family Group Sheet as before by using the following URL structure:

```
http://trees.ancestry.com/tree/TREE_ID/family/familygroup?fpid=PERSON_ID
```

You can find the TREE_ID and PERSON_ID by looking at the URL when you are on an individual's profile page.

There is no link to this page from the existing tree, so it is either a remnant of Old Ancestry that will be removed in the future, or a feature in the process of being added to the New Ancestry trees.

Answer (score 3):

Ancestry has reinstated the Family Group Sheet.  See [Ancestry Product update: Family Group Sheets are back!](https://blogs.ancestry.com/ancestry/2018/06/26/ancestry-product-update-family-group-sheets-are-back/) (Posted on the by Ancestry Team on June 26, 2018 in the category Website) for details.

Note that Ancestry says:

> You can access the Family Group Sheet by selecting the drop-down menu
>   for the tree you’re viewing in the upper left-hand corner, and then
>   choosing “Family Group Sheet” at the bottom of the list.

In the comments on the Facebook post where this blog post was shared, an admin says:

> [Y]ou can utilize the family group sheets only when viewing the family tree in either “pedigree view” or “family view".

In other words, the family group sheet feature is NOT accessed through the person's profile page, which is where we might expect it to be. (**UPDATE:** That was the case as of June 2018, but it has changed since I originally updated my answer.  For a demonstration of how to get to a Family Group Sheet from an individual's profile see the  screenshots [in PolyGeo's answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/15427/1006).)

When you are in the pedigree view or family view (the drop-line chart), click on the person whose family you want to focus on and look for the tools icon. Choose "View (his/her) family tree" to bring that individual into focus. Then from the drop-down menu shown in the blog post, you can select the family group sheet menu item.  In other words, make sure that the person whose family you want to see in the left-most position on the pedigree view before you invoke the Family Group Sheet view on the pedigree view or family view.

The blog post says:

> While in the Family Group Sheet view, selecting the **Profile** button for the focus person or their spouse will take you to that person’s profile page. Selecting **Search** will initiate a search for that person, and clicking on the name of any children or parents will refocus the family group sheet on that family member.

My previous answer from 2017 is below the line.

---

Another option for looking at the dates and locations of all the children in a marriage to see if it all makes sense is to turn on the option for Family Events on the Facts tab. This is an option on the Show menu, next to the add widget on the left-hand side of the page:

[image]

Turning this option on puts the births and deaths of immediate family members into the timeline of the selected profile.

Here on Susan Sweetsir's profile, you can see the births of her three children by John B. Lowell.  If you wanted to see all of John B. Lowell's children, including those by his first wife Hannah Sweetsir (Susan's sister), you could look at John's profile instead.  When using this method to trace the migration of a family, keep in mind that the father need not be present at a child's birth, and that a mother might have a child away from home, e.g. if she went to visit family for the birth of her child.

This does require scrolling, but so do Family Group Sheets when the families have many children.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In March 2018, I was specifically searching for a way to print family group sheets and came across this Q&A.

I am glad I did because the [answer from Harry](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/10550/19) was exactly what I was looking for.

Anyone coming across this now, the link above still works, but redirects to one a little simpler.

It's now

```
www.ancestry.com/family-tree/tree/TREE_ID/family/familygroup
```

As stated above, replace TREE_ID with the first set of numbers found in the web address on the person's profile page.

Comment: I am glad that my question and @HarryVervet's answer were helpful.  However, I do not think that the link you have provided will work to find the correct family group sheet *unless you are already on the person's profile page*.  For example, to find my 7th great grandfather Richard Boyens' family group sheet I use https://www.ancestry.com/family-tree/tree/32456697/family/familygroup?fpid=19031646651 whereas that of his father-in-law Martin Ustick is reached via https://www.ancestry.com/family-tree/tree/32456697/family/familygroup?fpid=28429309369

Comment: @PolyGeo I just tested Cassie's link by starting from www.ancestry.com/family-tree/tree/TREE_ID/family/ (in other words, from a family tree screen rather than a profile) and then adding the familygroup to the end. The FamilyGroup Sheet that was displayed was for the last-viewed person for that tree. (You can see which person is the last-viewed from the breadcrumb trail at the bottom of the screen in pedigree or drop-line chart view, or by using the TreeSearch button to open the new side panel for the search box and Home Person / Last Viewed person / List of all People menu items.)